# Calculating daily temperature gradiant from MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

Looking for some help on the following problem please.

I'm having a problem with calculating the daily temperature gradiant from a solar heated water tank. Basically, I'm trying to work out the rate of temperature loss each day.

I have a mysql database table with a timestamp and the current temp (int) of the tank which is stored every 5 mins.

```
timestamp          ¦   ct
2015-02-11 4:33    ¦   32
2015-02-11 3:33    ¦   32
2015-02-11 2:28    ¦   35
2015-02-11 1:23    ¦   51
2015-02-10 5:18    ¦   31
2015-02-10 4:13    ¦   31
2015-02-10 3:10    ¦   32
2015-02-10 2:58    ¦   33
2015-02-10 1:56    ¦33
```

e.g. The rate of change (oC/min) for 02-10 would be 33-31/(5:18-1:56) = 2/202mins = 0.0099
So I would like the query to return

```
2015-02-10, 0.0099
2015-02-12, 0.1
```

so far I have managed to find the min and max per day but not been able to get the correct time difference between when those two min and maxs happened.

```
select max(ct)- min(ct)as tempDiff, date(timestamp)
from homelog 
group by date(timestamp)
order by date(timestamp)
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to how to work out what timestamp corresponds to the time when the min and max values occurred so I can work out the difference. I know I can use timestampdiff but don't know how to get the values to pass it.

thanks

**Edit:**
Thanks to Gordon Linoff for giving me a hint I have now got the following

```
select date(maxTime),d1ct, d2ct, maxtime,mintime, timestampdiff(minute,maxTime,minTime),(d1ct-d2ct)/timestampdiff(minute,maxTime,minTime) from 
(select d1.ct as d1ct,min( h1.timestamp) as maxTime from 
(SELECT date(homelog.timestamp) as dte,MAX(ct) AS ct
FROM homelog
GROUP BY date(homelog.timestamp)
order by homelog.timestamp asc) d1
join homelog h1 on date(dte)=date(h1.timestamp)
and d1.ct = h1.ct
group by d1.ct, date(h1.timestamp)
order by h1.timestamp asc) d3
join 
(select d2.ct as d2ct,max( h3.timestamp) as minTime from 
(SELECT date(h2.timestamp) as dte2,min(ct) AS ct
FROM homelog h2
GROUP BY date(h2.timestamp)
order by h2.timestamp asc) d2
join homelog h3 on date(dte2)=date(h3.timestamp)
and d2.ct = h3.ct
group by d2.ct, date(h3.timestamp)
order by h3.timestamp asc ) d4 
on date(minTime)>=date(maxTime)
and date(minTime)<=date(maxTime)+ interval 1 day
where minTime>maxTime
```

Fudge at the end as I know my min temp will always occur within one day of my max but works for me.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Another question to which the answer is: "join the table *with itself*".

Comment: I agree but my question is about how to join. My join should be to the record that contains the max value for ct to get the actual timestamp of that record but joining to the date(timestamp) doesn't give me the correct timestamp. I was wondering if I could get the row number and use that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use your query as a subquery and join in the information:

```
select mm.*, maxct - minct as diff, hmin.timestamp, max.timestamp
from (select max(ct) as maxct, min(ct) as minct, date(timestamp) as dte
      from homelog 
      group by date(timestamp)
     ) mm join
     homelog hmin
     on date(hmin.timestamp) = mm.dte and hmin.ct = mm.minct join
     homelog hmax
     on date(hmax.timestamp) = mm.dte and hmax.ct = mm.maxct
order by dte;
```

This is going to have some problems, when there are duplicate min and max in each day.  If the values are really floating point values, this may rarely happen.  Otherwise, you need to decide what to do about them.  I think that explaining this is best done in another question, with sample data, desired results, and a good explanation of what you really want to do.

Comment: Yup, There will be ct's which have the same value in a day and therefore duplicate min and maxs. The values in ct are just integers, it was my gradiant that would be a float. The query you give is what I was trying but I can't do the join by a date(timestamp) as it doesn't give me the timestamp for the row containing the max (or min) ct value. I'm after how to do the join to find this row to return the timestamp of when the max (or min) ct was recorded. Then its just a case of doing the calculation.

Comment: @lambosprit . . . As I suggest in the answer, the question you asked isn't really the question you need answered.  You should ask another question with more complete details on what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
select date(l1.timestamp), max(l2.ct) - min(l1.ct) as deltaTemp, max(l2.timestamp) - min(l1.timestamp) as deltaTime
from homelog l1
inner join homelog l2 on date(l1.timestamp) = date(l2.timestamp)
group by date(l1.timestamp)
having l1.ct = min(l1.ct) and l2.ct = max(l2.ct)
```